# My Annotation View is not getting set proper in iphone 7

Tags: ios, annotations, mkmapview

I have older application, I'm updating its code to support IOS 10. Its working fine at my end however my client found that the annotation is not display in center of the screen in his iPhone 7, So annotation's view is getting cut from left side. Its working fine in all the devices I have(upto iPhone 6) and in simulators with iPhone 7.

Any suggestion where I suppose to look.
Thank you.

Comment: Client is having old iphone. Give him your device  :P

Comment: Lol, thank for mocking me, but client is using latest iPhone.

Comment: :D, :D Good catch, may i know who are you?

Comment: Plz add screenshot if possible

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem.
I assigned the values ​​of a class in a view that is displayed on the screen. However, on the iPhone 7 I used for testing, the `didSelect` delegate function was not being accessed. But in my iPhone 11 it worked.

I had this in my code:

```
func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, didSelect annotation: MKAnnotation) {
   if let sucursalSeleccionada = annotation as? StoreAnnotation{
        if self.stores.isEmpty{return}
        
        lblSucursal.text = sucursalSeleccionada.title
        lblDireccion.text = sucursalSeleccionada.subtitle
        let idTiendaSeleccionada = sucursalSeleccionada.idTienda
        let tiendaSeleccionada = self.stores.first(where: {$0.id == idTiendaSeleccionada})
        self.sucursal = tiendaSeleccionada
        self.seleccionoSucursal = true
        self.sucursalSeleccionada = tiendaSeleccionada
        self.nombreDeTienda = sucursalSeleccionada.title ?? ""
        viewTienda.isHidden = false
    }
}
```

My solution was to change the `MKAnnotation` type parameter to `MKAnnotationView` and when ensuring the parameter use its `.annotation` property.

I hope it works for you, greetings.

```
func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, didSelect view: MKAnnotationView) {
   if let sucursalSeleccionada = view.annotation as? StoreAnnotation{

        if self.stores.isEmpty{return}
        
        lblSucursal.text = sucursalSeleccionada.title
        lblDireccion.text = sucursalSeleccionada.subtitle
        let idTiendaSeleccionada = sucursalSeleccionada.idTienda
        let tiendaSeleccionada = self.stores.first(where: {$0.id == idTiendaSeleccionada})
        self.sucursal = tiendaSeleccionada
        self.seleccionoSucursal = true
        self.sucursalSeleccionada = tiendaSeleccionada
        self.nombreDeTienda = sucursalSeleccionada.title ?? ""
        viewTienda.isHidden = false
    }
}
```